# How compiler resolves the scope?

Tags: memory-management, data-structures, stack, cpu-architecture

I know what is stack and how they work .I also know that every function is allocated its own stack in memory and that is what makes the scope.
but the thing which confuses me is how compiler finds out that these names are declared in this scope . **does it unfolds the whole stack and checks if there is an entry for the given name**.(it seems exhausting)
consider this code:

```
void func(int a)
{
  cout<<a;
  cout<<b;
}
```

here stack of func will contain entry for **a** but when compiler encounters the name **b** it checks the stack and finds out that there is no entry for b. now question is how it checks , does it unfolds the whole stack.
and **what if this function is declared inside another function which contains b, does it have to unfold all the other stacks as well.**

Comment: The function is not allocated its own stack. The function allocates a stack frame on the process stack. This happens at run time, not compile time. As noted in the answer below, the compiler uses a hierarchy of symbol tables (or the logical equivalent thereof) to resolve scope issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers resolve the scope of variables through symbol tables. Each scope gets its own symbol table and these tables are organised in a hierarchical fashion based on the structure of the program.

When the compiler wants to resolve the scope of a variable, it will first check for its presence in the current scope's symbol table. If not found, it will try the parent scope's symbol table, and so forth.

Each symbol table should be relatively quick to search.

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_symbol_table.htm) for a visual example.